# Best way to send binary data with Thrift

Tags: thrift

I have a structure in c++ which stores bytes like this:

```
struct RemoteData 
{
    /// some other fields here

    unsigned char* buf;
    int bufLen;     
};
```

And I need to send this data to remote service, written in C++, via thrift. I found three ways how to map this structure to thrift idl:

1. Using container types like this:

   ```
   struct RemoteData 
   {
       1: list<BYTE> buf,
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Using `binary` type:

   ```
   struct RemoteData 
   {
       1: binary buf,
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Storing data in `string` type:

   ```
   struct RemoteData 
   {
       1: string buf,
       ...
   }
   ```

What is the best way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The value contained in thrift `string` type must be UTF8-encoded, otherwise some client won't be able to read it (Java thrift client for example).

Thrift `list<byte>` type will be converted into `std::vector<int8_t>` in c++, but in other languages it will be not so good (for example, in java it will be compiled into suboptimal `List<Byte>`.

The `binary` type is the best choice in terms of interoperability with clients in other languages and the correctness of protocol definition.

Since all 3 definitions produce messages of roughly the same size, I'd go with `binary`: even if you don't need interoperability with other languages now, you may need it in future.

Comment: But in thrift documentation http://thrift.apache.org/docs/types/ written about binary type "N.B.: This is currently a specialized form of the string type above, added to provide better interoperability with Java. The current plan-of-record is to elevate this to a base type at some point."

Comment: @DanilaNV This documentation is probably outdated: Thrift binary type is as stable, convenient and widely used as other types, so I don't see why it is not in the list of basic types yet.